# Responsive Carousel size to how many cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a beginner at JS and I've made a carousel, it works by moving the margin with every click and counting the clicks to reset back to the start once the user has clicked to the end. It all works how I would like it to however...

The problem with this carousel is that the number of clicks (basically the number of `<div class="caro">`'s within the container) needs to be manually input for both large and small device resolutions.

Is there a better way of doing it so that it doesn't matter how many cells within the carousel there are?

```js
var subButton = "#subButton";
var addButton = "#addButton";
var caro = "#caro";

var clicks = 0;

if (screen.width > 800) {
  $(addButton).click(function() {
    $(caro).animate({
      'margin-left': '-=180px'
    }, {
      duration: 400
    });
    clicks += 1;

    if (clicks > 3) {
      $(caro).animate({
        'margin-left': '0px'
      }, {
        duration: 400
      });
      clicks = 0;
    };
  });
} else {
  $(addButton).click(function() {
    $(caro).animate({
      'margin-left': '-=180px'
    }, {
      duration: 400
    });
    clicks += 1;

    if (clicks > 7) {
      $(caro).animate({
        'margin-left': '0px'
      }, {
        duration: 400
      });
      clicks = 0;
    };
  });
}

$(subButton).click(function() {
  $(caro).animate({
    'margin-left': '0px'
  }, {
    duration: 400
  });
  clicks = 0;
});
```

```css
.containercarousel {
  width: calc(100% - 90px);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0px 0 30px;
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;
}

.wrappercarousel {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1090px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.caro {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: 15px 0 15px 30px;
  float: left;
}

.css-carousel {
  width: 2400%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrappercarousel">
  <div class="containercarousel">
    <div class="css-carousel" id="caro">
      <div class="caro">
        <figure class="img100">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yyWQ8qC.png" alt="" />
        </figure><br> a
        <br>
      </div>

      <div class="caro">
        <figure class="img100">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yyWQ8qC.png" alt="" />
        </figure><br> b
        <br>
      </div>

      <div class="caro">
        <figure class="img100">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yyWQ8qC.png" alt="" />
        </figure><br> c
        <br>
      </div>

      <div class="caro">
        <figure class="img100">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yyWQ8qC.png" alt="" />
        </figure><br> d
        <br>
      </div>

      <div class="caro">
        <figure class="img100">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yyWQ8qC.png" alt="" />
        </figure><br> e
        <br>
      </div>

      <div class="caro">
        <figure class="img100">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yyWQ8qC.png" alt="" />
        </figure><br> f
        <br>
      </div>

      <div class="caro">
        <figure class="img100">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yyWQ8qC.png" alt="" />
        </figure><br> g
        <br>
      </div>

      <div class="caro">
        <figure class="img100">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yyWQ8qC.png" alt="" />
        </figure><br> h
        <br>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/4tFzEDL.png" id="subButton" style="float:left;  margin-top:-190px;" />
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/WGQCMT9.png" id="addButton" style="float:right;  margin-top:-190px;" />

  <div class="clearfix"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery's `.length` property will give you the number of elements returned by a selector.

for instance:

```
$("div#caro .caro").length; // 8
```

I will advise that you should avoid using the same names for the `id` and `class`. It's not forbidden, but it will most likely confuse you at some later point if this is a project you are planning on maintaining or building up in the future.